# Specify a TTL in the messages using WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I would create a WCF service with some methods: one of these methods would have a TTL (Time To Live) argument of byte type in order to set the maximum radius of forwarding to other nodes.
Since IP packets have a TTL field, is it possible to set this field using WCF in order to reach the same target?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for usual Socket communication you could do it with this:

[Socket.Ttl Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.ttl.aspx)

for WCF I'm not sure you can control it in the same way, for MSMQ bindings there ius a `TimeToLive` property of the binding as `TimeSpan` but is not the same thing as changing the TTL at the `IP` level, see here: [WCF / MSMQ "time-to-be-received has elapsed" dead letter queue issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1755907/wcf-msmq-time-to-be-received-has-elapsed-dead-letter-queue-issue)

I'm not sure if you could write your own WCF binding and be able to push to your value to the underlying socket as in the first link I mentioned above...

Answer (score 1):

Pretty late answer, but we faced the same issue recently.
Given that the TransportSettings is marked as obsolete, we did the following:

```
var udpDiscoveryEndpoint = new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint();

var customBinding = udpDiscoveryEndpoint.Binding as CustomBinding;
if (customBinding != null)
{
    TransportBindingElement transportBindingElement = customBinding.Elements.Find<TransportBindingElement>();
    if (transportBindingElement is UdpTransportBindingElement)
    {
       (transportBindingElement as UdpTransportBindingElement).TimeToLive = configuration.DiscoveryTtl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 4.0 the [UdpDiscoveryEndpoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.udpdiscoveryendpoint.transportsettings(v=vs.100).aspx) in WCF has a TimeToLive property that defaults to 1:

```
new UdpDiscoveryEndpoint().TransportSettings.TimeToLive
```

In .NET 4.5 it has been obsoleted and replaced with [UdpTransportBindingElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.discovery.udpdiscoveryendpoint.transportsettings(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
new UdpTransportBindingElement().TimeToLive
```